# How to create link make cakephp with twitter bootstrap

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

example:

```
<a class="btn btn-mini" href="#"><i class="icon-star"></i> Star</a>
```

i try by Html::Helpers like

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('i','', 
    array('class' => 'btn')), array('action' => '../link'));
```

but it not work !

Comment: what output it's giving you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'icon-star')) . " Star",
    array('action' => 'your_action'),
    array('class' => 'btn btn-mini', 'escape' => false)
);
```